# Observable and Webclient to get csv

Tags: .net, csv, webclient, system.reactive

I have a function in my lightswitch application that downloads a csv file from a site which i want to re-write using Rx framework and provide provide possibility to call it synchronously.

Provide below are the code snippets for old and new function. The new function however doesn't work, the call to ParseCSV never happens. I would like to know why and if exists a better solution, feel free to provide.

**Old Code:**

```
private void ObservableCollection<Data> collection;
public ObservableCollection<Data> GetData(string url, ObservableCollection<Data> targetCollection)
{

collection = targetCollection;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(OpenReadCompleted_ParseCSV);
    wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
}
return collection;
}

private void OpenReadCompleted_ParseCSV(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Error != null) return;

var webClient = sender as WebClient;
if (webClient == null) return;

try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
    {
        string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        ...
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error parsing CSV!\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

}

**New Code (with Rx):**

```
private void ObservableCollection<Data> collection;
public ObservableCollection<Data> GetData(string url, ObservableCollection<Data> targetCollection)
{
collection = targetCollection;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
{
    var result = Observable.FromEventPattern<OpenReadCompletedEventHandler, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs>
                 (
                    ev => webClient.OpenReadCompleted += ev,
                    ev => webClient.OpenReadCompleted -= ev
                 )
                 .Select(o => o.EventArgs.Result)
                 .FirstOrDefault()
                 .ParseCSV();

    // Call the Async method
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
}
return collection;
}

private void ParseCSV(this Stream stream)
{
try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
    {
        string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        ...
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get history data!\n" + ex.Message);
}
}
```

Comment: Just a quick hint - you're misusing Rx - this should all be done in a single query without a `FirstOrDefault` in sight...

Comment: It's my first attempt to make the call synchronous (idea from Functional Alchemy: Making Silverlight synchronous)

Comment: Rx is all about being asynchronous. If you try to make it synchronous you're very likely to get deadlocks. Do you use the tool "LinqPad"? If not, you should download it. It's great for trying Rx code in a "scratch pad" environment.

Comment: Well it states "Rx is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style query operators". I'm using Rx to have my events accessible as observable collections and therefore use the Linq advantages we have today.

Answer (score 2):

It's tough to know what you are going for (I think you tried to dumb down the code for posting on StackOverflow and a lot got lost in translation), but I think there are few things I would change about this.

One thing I noticed is that you are parsing the result back on the main thread. There are reasons you might do this, but you might consider this:

```
//Note the void here. Is your intention to return a new collection or contribute
//to an existing one? I assumed the latter and changed the method to be more clear
//that this method causes side effects.
public void GetData(string url, ObservableCollection<Data> targetCollection)
{
        var result = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<OpenReadCompletedEventHandler, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs>
            (
                ev => webClient.OpenReadCompleted += ev,
                ev => webClient.OpenReadCompleted -= ev
            )
            .Select(o => ParseCSV(o.EventArgs.Result));

    result.Subscribe(targetCollection.Add);
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
}

//This method now returns a Data object read from a Stream
private static Data ParseCSV(Stream stream)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            //...
            return data;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Use Exception.ToString(). You get error and stack trace information
        //For this error as well as any inner exceptions. Nice!
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get history data!\n" + ex.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here, for each value that comes back from the webClient request (there will only be one), we are *projecting* the result into your `Data` class, rather than doing the conversion outside of the observable stream.

I made some minor modifications to your methods. I don't particularly like code like this with side effects (passing in the collection to contribute to seems like a vector for bugs), but I'll allow it. Other than that, I think this should work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your provided solution and thoughtful remarks. For that i've marked your answer useful. It's not yet the complete solution for i want to have a synchronous variation. Could you add that?

Answer (score 0):

**An Improved Answer for WPF**

Create a new project and paste this code in your MainWindow.  Add a button named XBStart and you are all set if you hook up the click handler to XBStart_Click.  Run the project and click the button!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RX.DataReady += new RX.OnData(RX_DataReady);
    }

    private void RX_DataReady(ObservableCollection<string> Data)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    private void XBStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RX.GetData("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
}

public static class RX
{
    public delegate void OnData(ObservableCollection<string> Data);

    public static event OnData DataReady;

    private static WebClient webClient;

    private static ObservableCollection<string> TheData { get; set; }

    private static void Notify()
    {
        if (DataReady != null)
        {
            DataReady(TheData);
        }
    }

    public static void GetData(string url)
    {
        webClient = new WebClient();
        TheData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        var result = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<OpenReadCompletedEventHandler, 
                              OpenReadCompletedEventArgs>
            (
                ev => webClient.OpenReadCompleted += ev,
                ev => webClient.OpenReadCompleted -= ev
            )
            .Select(o => Parse.CSV(o.EventArgs.Result));

        result.Subscribe<string>(p =>
        {
            TheData.Add(p);
            Notify();
        });
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
}

public static class Parse
{
    //This method now returns a Data object read from a Stream
    public static string CSV(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //...
                return contents;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Use Exception.ToString(). 
            //You get error and stack trace information
            //For this error as well as any inner exceptions. Nice!
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get history data!\n" +
                                               ex.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: All this post has done is take the existing answer and put it into a WPF window's code. The OP was not at all asking about WPF, and this has added *nothing* that relates to the question which was asked.

Comment: True but that's what the title of the post indicated "An improved Answer for WPF"  I did this to help others (including myself) who have same problem in WPF land!